# SQL DropDownList - ListItem inserts

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, drop-down-menu

I have a `dropdownlist` (DDL) for a user to select between two values to insert into the database via codebehind/stored procedure file. All my forms work well with the DDL method except when I try to add the DDL in an `'if else'` statement. When I do this the form acts normal as if the information was inserted but doesn't insert values into the database.

**ASPX CODE**

```
<tr><td>Active: </td><td>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListActive" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    Width="128px" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Height="22px">
    <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td></tr>
```

**CODE-BEHIND:**

```
if (DropDownListActive.SelectedValue == "Select")
{
    Label1.Text = "Please select Yes or No.";
    return;
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Active", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3));
    cmd.Parameters["@Active"].Value = DropDownListActive.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Which event you have handled?

Comment: @AVD Button_Click, when I click submit it carries the method that contains the above.

Comment: So, when you take the        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Active", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3));
        cmd.Parameters["@Active"].Value = DropDownListActive.SelectedValue;
out of the if else, it will persist them into the database?

Comment: @nick - Why you set AutoPostBack and AppendDataBoundItems properties? Is there any code in Page_Load event to bind or to do something else?.

Comment: @AVD Thanks for pointing that out, I'm use to having the list being populated via database. I removed those and discoved I had a undocumented column in my database (missing from ER Diagram). After adding the command parameters for that and cleaning up the code. It works now.